# Fedora 21 - Unable to log in to user account

Tags: linux, fedora

I am interested in turning my old Windows XP computer with a 32 bit processor into a Fedora computer. I have installed the 32 bit version of Fedora 21 on the computer with no problems at all, wiping the hard drive of Windows XP and all other data. Since installing Fedora 21, I have been unable to use the computer for anything because once Fedora loads the screen where you select an account to log in to, I choose to log in to my account, and then Fedora immediately displays an error message saying, "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. All extensions have been disabled as a precaution." Whenever I get this message, I hit the enter key because my mouse cursor does not show up to allow me to press the cancel button in a normal way. After doing this, I am returned to the login screen and the process repeats itself.

What can I do to resolve the issue? It is important to note that the computer does not have an internet connection.

Comment: Are you able to login from a full screen terminal? You can do this by pressing CTRL+ALT+F2. You may need to try a different F# key depending on which one your graphical environment is running in.

Comment: @Dylan What do you mean when you say try a different F# key? I have successfully booted into the full screen terminal. Now what?

Comment: I meant like F3, F4, F5 etc. You have 12 terminals corresponding to the F# keys. One of those will be your graphical environment the rest are the text terminals. Type "journalctl -xn 30" to get the last 30 lines (or whatever number you like) from your system log, paying close attention to anything that looks like an error message. You're more likely to get something interesting if you do this immediately after attempting to log in through the GUI.

Comment: @Dylan What could show up as being a problem? I see nothing in the log that sticks out to me as being a problem. I have checked the log using both the root user as well as the account which I am trying to log in under, and neither show anything.

Comment: Let's continue this in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20726/fedora-21-unable-to-log-in-to-user-account

Comment: This is typically a video driver problem (broken driver or video hardware is too old). You should find relevant information in `$HOME/.xsession-errors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what went wrong, but reinstalling Fedora 21 resolved the problem. Since it was a fresh install in the first place, I was not concerned with losing any data. Since then, I have upgraded to Fedora 22 and everything is working smoothly.